# Generating Combinations/Permutations (t-sets on v symbols)

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation, combinations, combinatorics

I'm dealing with covering arrays and need some guidance about generating sets (given certain parameters) for computing whether an array is a covering array or not.

I'm given two inputs to parse - `t` and `v` as integers. `v` contains the number of unique symbols (integers) in the array. This can be assumed to be a set of any integers. The integer `t` represents the length of symbols I want to grab from this set.

So for example, assume `v = 3` for `{0,1,2}` as symbols, and `t = 2`. Then I will be generating the combinations `{ (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), ..., (2,2) }`. In general, I will be generating `v^t` combinations. I am wondering if there is a better algorithm than the one I have been using which may be, perhaps, less computationally expensive.

Basically what I am doing is counting in a different base. So, for instance, in the above example I initially start with an array that has `t` spaces allocated to 0. On each pass, I increment the least significant bit and convert this to a set or some other data structure to hold my combinations. Once the least significant bit overflows, I set it to 0 and increment the next significant bit. It's all counting in different bases. So I'd end up with the following output for `t=2` and `v=3`:

```
00
01
02
10
11
12
20
21
22
```

My biggest question is this - is this a permutation or combination problem? I'm a little fuzzy on the details between the two. I believe it is permutation just because repetition occurs, and because order doesn't matter.

Likewise, is this algorithm decent enough to (potentially) handle a large `v`? I am given the parameter that `t` will be 2 or 3, but `v` is unknown. Is there a well-known algorithm for computing length-`t` sets on `v` symbols? For reference, I am using C++ to do this.

Comment: The amortized cost of counting goes **down** as `v` increases, because you spend a smaller percentage of the time propagating the carry.

Comment: @bgoers: In your example {01} and {10} are different, so its not a combinations only problem - possible permutations of combinations.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Thanks for the input. So assuming (which I safely can in this case due to constraints) that v <= 500, do you believe this will be fine? At that point I'm assuming it's more a question of space complexity, but this is running on a rather large cluster so I am not too terribly worried..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dealing with `variations with repetitions`. There's plenty of examples, both on SO and all over the Internet. As for your algorithm, it's complexity will be at least the size of the output - which you've already pointed it out - it'll be Ω(v^t). If bit-wise operations work for you (i.e. fit with the rest of the implementation) then yes, you can do it this way.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the info. I have been searching high and low for a specific name for this type of problem, just hadn't nailed it down specifically.